# PHP get data from DELETE request

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am using jquery plugin for multiple file upload. Everything is working fine, except delete the images. Firebug say that JS it is sending DELETE request to the function. How can I get data from delete request?

PHP delete code:

```
public function deleteImage() {
    //Get the name in the url
        $file = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $r = $this->session->userdata('id_user');
    $q=$this->caffe_model->caffe_get_one_user($r);
        $cff_name= $q->name;
    $cff_id = $q->id_caffe;       

    $w = $this->gallery_model->gallery_get_one_user($gll_id);
    $gll_name = $w->name;
        $success = unlink("./public/img/caffe/$cff_name/$gll_name/" . $file);
        $success_th = unlink("./public/img/caffe/$cff_name/$gll_name/thumbnails/" . $file);

        //info to see if it is doing what it is supposed to 
        $info = new stdClass();
        $info->sucess = $success;
        $info->path = $this->getPath_url_img_upload_folder() . $file;
        $info->file = is_file($this->getPath_img_upload_folder() . $file);
        if (IS_AJAX) {//I don't think it matters if this is set but good for error checking in the console/firebug
            echo json_encode(array($info));
        } else {     //here you will need to decide what you want to show for a successful delete
            var_dump($file);
        }
    }
```

and JS is using jQuery-File-Upload plugin: [link](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Generally, if the DELETE request sends data in the request body, you can read the data by using the following code:

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Depending on the encoding of the data (usually JSON or form-encoded), you use `json_decode` or `parse_str` to read the data into usable variables.

For a simple example, see [this article](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2008/accessing-incoming-put-data-from-php), where the author uses form-encoded data to handle a `PUT` request. `DELETE` works similarly.

---

In your case however, it looks like the file name is read from the request URL (the call to `$this->uri->segment(3);`). When I look at your code, it seems that the variable `$gll_id` is not initailized and you don't check if the resulting object `$w` and the variable `$gll_name` are empty. Maybe this is causing the delete to fail. Turn on error logging with `ini_set("log_errors",1);` and have a look at your server error log. If the unlink fails, the error log should contain the path PHP tried to unlink - it's likely that the path is not correct.

Comment: I bit lost (I have never worked with this). How can I get data from individual input?

Comment: It seams the file_get_contents("php://input") is not working wiht enctype="multipart/form-data" o.O

Comment: @Sasha I have added an additional explanation.